Program is destroying inputs
I am trying to get my program to grab or write info from/to a "addressbook.txt", but it only does those halfway, with messed up inputs into the file.
I believe it is getting stuck with all of the cin's, but it is displaying more than one at a time. I was suggested the idea of using push.back somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out how, or where I would put it.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class addressType {
private:
    std::string street;
    std::string city;
    std::string state;
    std::string zipCode;

public:
    addressType(std::string str, std::string cty, std::string st, std::string zip) 
        : street(str), city(cty), state(st), zipCode(zip) {}

    void printAddress() const {
        std::cout << street << ", " << city << ", " << state << " " << zipCode << std::endl;
    }
};

class dateType {
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

public:
    dateType(int d, int m, int y) : day(d), month(m), year(y) {}

    void printDate() const {
        std::cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
    }
};

class PersonType {
protected:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;

public:
    PersonType(std::string fName, std::string lName) 
        : firstName(fName), lastName(lName) {}

    std::string getLastName() const {
        return lastName;
    }
};

class extPersonType : public PersonType {
private:
    addressType address;
    dateType dateOfBirth;
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string email;
    std::string classification;

public:
    extPersonType(std::string fName, std::string lName, addressType addr, dateType dob, 
                  std::string phone, std::string emailAddr, std::string classif) 
        : PersonType(fName, lName), address(addr), dateOfBirth(dob), 
          phoneNumber(phone), email(emailAddr), classification(classif) {}

    void printInfo() const {
        std::cout << firstName << " " << lastName << std::endl;
        address.printAddress();
        std::cout << "Phone: " << phoneNumber << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Email: " << email << std::endl;
        std::cout << "DOB: "; dateOfBirth.printDate(); std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::string getClassification() const {
        return classification;
    }
};

class AddressBookType {
private:
    std::vector<extPersonType> entries;

public:
    void loadFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
        std::ifstream file(filename);
        std::string fName, lName, street, city, state, zip, phone, email, classif;
        int day, month, year;

        while (file >> fName >> lName >> street >> city >> state >> zip >> day >> month >> year >> phone >> email >> classif) {
            addressType addr(street, city, state, zip);
            dateType dob(day, month, year);
            extPersonType person(fName, lName, addr, dob, phone, email, classif);
            entries.push_back(person);
        }
    }

    void sortByLastName() {
        std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), [](const extPersonType& a, const extPersonType& b) {
            return a.getLastName() < b.getLastName();
        });
    }

    void searchByLastName(const std::string& lastName) const {
        for (const auto& person : entries) {
            if (person.getLastName() == lastName) {
                person.printInfo();
                return;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Person not found. Adding new entry." << std::endl;
        addNewEntry(lastName);
    }

    void addNewEntry(const std::string& lastName) const {
        std::string fName, street, city, state, zip, phone, email, classif;
        int day, month, year;

        std::cout << "Enter first name: ";
        std::cin >> fName;
        std::cout << "Enter street: ";
        std::cin >> street;
        std::cout << "Enter city: ";
        std::cin >> city;
        std::cout << "Enter state in form of AZ, CO, or NY: ";
        std::cin >> state;
        std::cout << "Enter zip code: ";
        std::cin >> zip;    
        std::cout << "Enter day of birth: ";
        std::cin >> day;
        std::cout << "Enter month of birth: ";
        std::cin >> month;
        std::cout << "Enter year of birth: ";
        std::cin >> year;
        std::cout << "Enter phone number: ";
        std::cin >> phone;
        std::cout << "Enter email: ";
        std::cin >> email;
        std::cout << "Enter classification: ";
        std::cin >> classif;

        addressType addr(street, city, state, zip);
        dateType dob(day, month, year);
        extPersonType person(fName, lastName, addr, dob, phone, email, classif);


        std::ofstream file("addressbook.txt", std::ios::app);
        file << fName << " " << lastName << " " << street << " " << city << " " << state << " " << zip << " "
             << day << " " << month << " " << year << " " << phone << " " << email << " " << classif << std::endl;
    }

    void printAllBetweenLastNames(const std::string& start, const std::string& end) const {
        for (const auto& person : entries) {
            if (person.getLastName() >= start && person.getLastName() <= end) {
                std::cout << person.getLastName() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    void printByClassification(const std::string& classif) const {
        for (const auto& person : entries) {
            if (person.getClassification() == classif) {
                std::cout << person.getLastName() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    AddressBookType addressBook;
    addressBook.loadFromFile("addressbook.txt");
    addressBook.sortByLastName();

    std::string lastNameToSearch;
    std::cout << "Enter last name to search: ";
    std::cin >> lastNameToSearch;
    addressBook.searchByLastName(lastNameToSearch);

    std::string continueInput;
    std::cout << "Do you want to search for another last name? (yes/no): ";
    std::cin >> continueInput;

    while (continueInput == "yes") {
        std::cout << "Enter last name to search: ";
        std::cin >> lastNameToSearch;
        addressBook.searchByLastName(lastNameToSearch);
        std::cout << "Do you want to search for another last name? (yes/no): ";
        std::cin >> continueInput;
    }

    return 0;
}


Ive tried to adjust the format to no avail

Now this is a good opportunity to learn what a debugger is and how it can help me diagnose problems?.

Please show us an example of input that doesn't work.

@yksisarbinen I am currently away from home, but if the last name searched initially is not found, it stores that, asks for the first name, and then the street name, which also writes correctly. The problem presents itself once the cin for city comes up, as it asks for city, state, and zip code all at the time. The larger issue is it then turns those inputs into numbers.

Let me guess. When asked for street you enter something like Mary Avenue or something else with a space inside?

@yksisarvinen are spaces just completely screwing me over?

Yes. std::cin >> will read up until first whitespace, be it just a space or newline character. Anything else left in stream will be consumed on next attempt to read from it. You could use std::getline instead, but be aware that they don't mix straight out of the box

@yksisarvinen That is something im definitely writing down somewhere, c++ is clearly not my thing

The code in a question should be a [mre]. You should not show us "grab or write info from/to a 'addressbook.txt'"; you should show us "messed up inputs". You could have either getting input data via std::cin or storing data in a file, but not both. Examine the data in between to determine which of the two has the problem, then eliminate the other. Skip the steps that are not needed (for example, skip the initial search and just assume it was unsuccessful). Simplify down to half a dozen lines or so.

@JacobJones -- As mentioned, you should have whittled down all of this code down to the bare minimum.  If you had done that, something like this would have, at the very least, directed you into investigating why std::cin stops at the space.

tip: write less code, test & debug more. Two lines to see the effect: std::cin >> x; std::cout << x;
